Error installing talos for Python in Colab
I need talos for a hyperparameter grid search, and I'm working in google colab.
When I run pip install talos in colab I get this error:
Collecting talos
  Downloading talos-1.3-py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 56.4/56.4 kB 1.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from talos) (2.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: statsmodels>=0.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from talos) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wrangle in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from talos) (0.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from talos) (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from talos) (2.0.3)
Collecting astetik (from talos)
  Using cached astetik-1.13-py3-none-any.whl (5.4 MB)
Collecting sklearn (from talos)
  Using cached sklearn-0.0.post12.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I have uninstalled scikit-learn and reinstalled. numpy, scipy, and wrangle are all installed and up to date.
I've downloaded the master talos file and tried to install from a local directory.
I continue to get this error and I'm not sure what to troubleshoot next.

This issue is resolved in Talos 1.4 version which is at this date the current version.
